# Validate date with 3 letter abbreviation and numbers?

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I have tried searching but I can't seem to find a question that encompasses my criteria.

I am new to jQuery and have been asked to create a site with a datepicker module.

I have used the standard jQuery one, and customised it accordingly, however as well as using the Datepicker user input is also an option.

I have to ensure the user input either follows DD/MM/YYYY or DD/JAN/YYYY (using three letter abbreviation).

I was thinking this is probably a reg-ex job, but am not familiar with it as of yet and cannot find an expression online matching my needs.

Is regex the best way, and if so can anyone provide me with any further insight?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Yup, regex is the only way. You can make the validation as complex or as dumb as you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regular expression expert but reading other posts on this subject i have tried to make this expression that validates dates in the format DD/MM/YYY or DD/JAN .../YY and years between 1970-2019.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!--DD/MM/YYYY or DD/JAN/YYYY 1970-2019:-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cli').click(function(){
    var str=$('#field').val()
    if(str.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/((0[1-9]|1[012])|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))\/(19[789]\d|20[01]\d)$/)){
        alert('yes')
        }else{alert('no')}
    })
})
</script>
<input name="" type="text" id="field">
<input name="" type="button" id="cli" value="Test">
</body>
</html>
```

If you try this document in your Web browser and enter the dates in the text field, when you'll click on the button the date will be validated
Repeat: i am not an expert and i encourage you test this solution
If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.